# Global table under TabPane - JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, tabpanel

I am going through the Oracle tutorial with tables, and have implemented my own tabPane into this code. What I want is for the table to be a global table, so that when I go onto tab 2, it is the exact same as it is on Tab 1, just only that i can edit certain columns in tab 2 compared to editing it all in tab 1.

Is there anyway this can be done instead of basically duplicating code and creating a second table, which i believe is tedious as I don't want two tables, I want one global table.

```
public class TableSample extends Application {

    private TableView<Person> table = new TableView<Person>();
    private final ObservableList<Person> data =
            FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new Person("Jacob", "Smith", "jacob.smith@example.com"),
            new Person("Isabella", "Johnson", "isabella.johnson@example.com"));

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private TableView table = new TableView();

    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());

        TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();

        Tab tab1 = new Tab("Tab 1");
        tabPane.getTabs().add(tab1);

        Tab tab2 = new Tab("Tab 2");
        tabPane.getTabs().add(tab2);

        table.setEditable(true);

        TableColumn firstNameCol = new TableColumn("First Name");
        firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("firstName"));
        firstNameCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        firstNameCol.setOnEditCommit(
            new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Person, String>>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(CellEditEvent<Person, String> t) {
                    ((Person) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                            t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                            ).setFirstName(t.getNewValue());
                }
            }
        );

        TableColumn lastNameCol = new TableColumn("Last Name");
        lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("lastName"));
        lastNameCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        lastNameCol.setOnEditCommit(
            new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Person, String>>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(CellEditEvent<Person, String> t) {
                    ((Person) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                        t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                        ).setLastName(t.getNewValue());
                }
            }
        );

        TableColumn emailCol = new TableColumn("Email");
        emailCol.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("email"));
        emailCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        emailCol.setOnEditCommit(
            new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Person, String>>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(CellEditEvent<Person, String> t) {
                    ((Person) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                        t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                        ).setEmail(t.getNewValue());
                }
            }
        );

        table.setItems(data);
        table.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol, lastNameCol, emailCol);

        final VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(tabPane, table);

        ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().addAll(vbox);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static class Person {

        private final SimpleStringProperty firstName;
        private final SimpleStringProperty lastName;
        private final SimpleStringProperty email;

        private Person(String fName, String lName, String email) {
            this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(fName);
            this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lName);
            this.email = new SimpleStringProperty(email);
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName.get();
        }

        public void setFirstName(String fName) {
            firstName.set(fName);
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName.get();
        }

        public void setLastName(String fName) {
            lastName.set(fName);
        }

        public String getEmail() {
            return email.get();
        }

        public void setEmail(String fName) {
            email.set(fName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you must create a second (and more, as much as you need) TableView: each Node can have exactly one parent. You can share the data between them.

Comment: @kleopatra I can share the data between them? But, however I want it so that if i update/edit data on for example tab 2, the data on tab 1 is also edited.

Comment: exactly, the update happens automatically if you let both tables share the same list of items

Comment: @kleopatra is there a certain function/call to let both tables share the same list of items?

Comment: I feel like this question has been asked before. The solutions are using a VBox or a SplitPane. If you use a VBox, put the TabPane in first and the TableView in second. If you use a SplitPane, put the TabPane in the Top and the TableView at the bottom.

Comment: @Sedrick Forgive me if I'm being misunderstanding, but is it as simple as creating another VBox, and grouping that to a scene, and simply stating that when you goto Tab 2, just trigger the second scene?

Comment: table1.setItems(myItems), table2.setItems(myItems) .. ?

Comment: btw, that tutorial code you copied is just ... crap (not your fault, of course, but Oracle's!) . No need for edit handlers, instead let the data item expose properties and use those the valueFactories. There are many examples here on SO

Comment: _creating a second table, which i believe is tedious_ you believe wrong :)  _as I don't want two tables, I want one global table_ if you want two tabs then you _do need_ two tables.

Comment: @kleopatra must be easier then to create a second table, set the items, and simply set the contents of tab2 to the second table?

Comment: just do it and you'll see that is the right-thing-to-do ;)

Answer (score -1):

Your code structure is already setup correctly. You just need to add `Nodes` to the different `Tabs`

**Key Code:** You need to add a root node to each `Tab`. Each root node will hold the other nodes that give each `Tab` it looks.

```
    Tab tab1 = new Tab("Tab 1");
    Label tab1Label = new Label("Use tab1Root to add nodes for tab1!");
    StackPane tab1Root = new StackPane(tab1Label);
    tab1Root.setPrefSize(500, 500);
    tab1.setContent(tab1Root);
    tabPane.getTabs().add(tab1);

    Tab tab2 = new Tab("Tab 2");
    Button tab2Button = new Button("Press Me!");
    tab2Button.setOnAction((event) -> {
        System.out.println("Use tab2Root to add nodes for tab2!");
    });
    StackPane tab2Root = new StackPane(tab2Button);
    tab2Root.setPrefSize(500, 500);
    tab2.setContent(tab2Root);
    tabPane.getTabs().add(tab2);
```

**Full Code**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableColumn.CellEditEvent;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TestingGround extends Application
{
    private TableView<Person> table = new TableView<Person>();
    private final ObservableList<Person> data
            = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                    new Person("Jacob", "Smith", "jacob.smith@example.com"),
                    new Person("Isabella", "Johnson", "isabella.johnson@example.com"));

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    public void start(Stage stage)
    {
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());

        TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();

        Tab tab1 = new Tab("Tab 1");
        Label tab1Label = new Label("Use tab1Root to add nodes for tab1!");
        StackPane tab1Root = new StackPane(tab1Label);
        tab1Root.setPrefSize(500, 500);
        tab1.setContent(tab1Root);
        tabPane.getTabs().add(tab1);

        Tab tab2 = new Tab("Tab 2");
        Button tab2Button = new Button("Press Me!");
        tab2Button.setOnAction((event) -> {
            System.out.println("Use tab2Root to add nodes for tab2!");
        });
        StackPane tab2Root = new StackPane(tab2Button);
        tab2Root.setPrefSize(500, 500);
        tab2.setContent(tab2Root);
        tabPane.getTabs().add(tab2);

        table.setEditable(true);

        TableColumn firstNameCol = new TableColumn("First Name");
        firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("firstName"));
        firstNameCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        firstNameCol.setOnEditCommit(
                new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Person, String>>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(CellEditEvent<Person, String> t)
            {
//                ((Person) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
//                        t.getTablePosition().getRow())).setFirstName(t.getNewValue());
            }
        }
        );

        TableColumn lastNameCol = new TableColumn("Last Name");
        lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("lastName"));
        lastNameCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        lastNameCol.setOnEditCommit(
                new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Person, String>>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(CellEditEvent<Person, String> t)
            {
//                ((Person) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
//                        t.getTablePosition().getRow())).setLastName(t.getNewValue());
            }
        }
        );

        TableColumn emailCol = new TableColumn("Email");
        emailCol.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("email"));
        emailCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        emailCol.setOnEditCommit(
                new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Person, String>>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(CellEditEvent<Person, String> t)
            {
//                ((Person) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
//                        t.getTablePosition().getRow())).setEmail(t.getNewValue());
            }
        }
        );

        table.setItems(data);
        table.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol, lastNameCol, emailCol);

        final VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(tabPane, table);

        ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().addAll(vbox);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static class Person
    {

        private final SimpleStringProperty firstName;
        private final SimpleStringProperty lastName;
        private final SimpleStringProperty email;

        private Person(String fName, String lName, String email)
        {
            this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(fName);
            this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lName);
            this.email = new SimpleStringProperty(email);
        }

        public String getFirstName()
        {
            return firstName.get();
        }

        public void setFirstName(String fName)
        {
            firstName.set(fName);
        }

        public String getLastName()
        {
            return lastName.get();
        }

        public void setLastName(String fName)
        {
            lastName.set(fName);
        }

        public String getEmail()
        {
            return email.get();
        }

        public void setEmail(String fName)
        {
            email.set(fName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's really helpful. My question is as i'm not as familiar with JavaFX as I am with other code, the "tab2Button.setOnAction" can I simply add code into that to make only certain elements in the table editable?

Comment: @tempaah, I think you need to take the time to get familiar with JavaFX. Do more tutorials until you are comfortable with JavaFX.

Comment: @Sedrick I would say im familiar-ish with JavaFX, im just wondering if the Button is like an example, im assuming you mean by that code, put the table into the tabs through the StackPane. Using e.g. `StackPane tab1Root = new StackPane(tableView);` and simple setting the contents of that tab to that root.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: I thought your goal was to have different `Tabs` and one `TableView`?